# ¿Cómo eliminar datos de una variable de Session en php?

Tags: php

Hola que tal tengo un pequeño problema, estoy intentando remover los productos agregados que están almacenados dentro una variable de session mediante un código aleatorio como se puede apreciar en el código siguiente.

Este es el código donde agrego los productos, como podrán notar se puede agregar un mismo producto con un id temporal, esto con el fin de agregar diferentes medidas del mismo, es por esa razón que agregue un código aleatorio

```
session_start(['name'=>'SPM']);

        if (empty($_SESSION['datos_item'][$id])) {

            // Función para agregar código aleatorio a la variable de session
            function codAleatorio($length = 5) {
                return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
            }
            $codigoitem  = codAleatorio();

            // Agregar id temporal
            $c=true;
            $cc=1;
            While($c==true){
                if(isset($_SESSION['datos_item'][$id.'-'.$cc])){# Verifica si el id Existe
                    $cc++;
                }else{
                    $id=$id.'-'.$cc;
                    $c=false;
                }
            }

            $_SESSION['datos_item'][$id]=[
                "ID"=>$campos['item_id'],
                "Coditem"=>$codigoitem,
                "Codigo"=>$campos['item_codigo'],
                "Nombre"=>$campos['item_nombre'],
                "Detalle"=>$campos['item_detalle'],
                "Precio"=>$campos['item_precio'],
                "Lamina"=>$lamina,
                "Metro"=>$metro,
                "Tipo"=>$tipos['tipo_nombre'],
                "Medida"=>$medidas['medida_nombre'],
                "Cantidad"=>$cantidad,
                "Descuento"=>$descuento
            ];
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"recargar",
                "Titulo"=>"Porducto agregado",
                "Texto"=>"el producto fue agregado",
                "Tipo"=>"success"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }else{
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"El producto no se pudo seleccionar",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }
```

Aquí un ejemplo en la vista
[image: Como se puede apreciar en la vista se puede agregar el mismo producto]

Este el código para remover los datos donde recupero el código de la vista mediante POST, sale la alerta de "Producto Removido" pero no remueve el producto

```
/* Recuperar el código */
        $codigo=mainModel::decryption($_POST['codigo_eliminar_producto']);
        $codigo=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($codigo);

        /* Iniciando la seción */
        session_start(['name'=>'SPM']);

        unset($_SESSION['datos_item'][$codigo]);
        

        if (empty($_SESSION['datos_item'][$codigo])) {

            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"recargar",
                "Titulo"=>"Producto Removido",
                "Texto"=>"El producto fue removido con exito",
                "Tipo"=>"success"
            ];

        }else{
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"No se pudo remover los datos del producto",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
        }
        echo json_encode($alerta);
```

Esta es la vista

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-dark table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="text-center roboto-medium">
                        <th>PRODUCTO</th>
                        <th>TIPO</th>
                        <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                        <th>UNIDAD</th>
                        <th>DESCUENTO</th>
                        <th>MEDIDA</th>
                        <th>PRECIO TOTAL</th>
                        <th>SUBTOTAL</th>
                        <th>COLOR</th>
                        <th>REMOVER</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        if (isset($_SESSION['datos_item']) && count($_SESSION['datos_item'])>=1) {
                            $_SESSION['prestamo_total']=0;
                            $_SESSION['prestamo_producto']=0;

                            foreach ($_SESSION['datos_item'] as $productos) {
                                $espesor=$productos['Lamina']*$productos['Metro'];
                                $cantidad=$productos['Cantidad']+$espesor;
                                $precio=$cantidad*$productos['Precio'];
                                $descuento=$precio-($precio*$productos['Descuento']/100);
                                $subtotal=$descuento;
                                $subtotal=number_format($subtotal,2,'.','');
                               
                     ?>
                    <tr class="text-center" id="addtable">
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Nombre']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Tipo']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $cantidad; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Medida']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Descuento'].PORCENTAJE; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Lamina']." X ".$productos['Metro']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo MONEDA.$precio; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo MONEDA.$subtotal; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="<?php echo $productos['Nombre']; ?>" data-content="<?php echo $productos['Detalle']; ?>">
                                <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!------ENVIO DE DATOS PARA REMOVER EL PRODUCTO-------->
                            <form class="FormularioAjax" action="<?php echo SERVERURL; ?>ajax/cotizacionesAjax.php" method="POST" data-form="loans" autocomplete="off">
                                <input type="hidden" name="codigo_eliminar_producto" value="<?php echo mainModel::encryption($productos['Coditem']) ?>">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                            $_SESSION['prestamo_total']+=$subtotal;
                            $_SESSION['prestamo_producto']+=$cantidad;

                             }

                 ?>
                    <tr class="text-center bg-light">
                        <td><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                        <td><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['prestamo_producto']; ?> Cant.</strong></td>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td><strong><?php echo MONEDA.number_format($_SESSION['prestamo_total'],2,'.',''); ?></strong></td>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }else{
                            $_SESSION['prestamo_total']=0;
                            $_SESSION['prestamo_producto']=0;
                     ?>
                    <tr class="text-center" >
                        <td colspan="11">No seleccionaste un producto</td>
                        
                    </tr>

                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Se los agradezco de antemano a los que puedan ayudarme

Comment: ¿Según tú, si esto se cumple `if (empty($_SESSION['datos_item'][$codigo])) {` debe ocurrir la eliminación del dato en la variable de sesión? No tendría mucho sentido realmente. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema.

Comment: No será que limpiar_cadena te está entregando otro código??

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo que hace es que mediante unset se vacié el array mediante el índice $codigo, una vez hecho eso en la condicional hace la comprobación donde. Si la variable de $_SESSION['datos_item'] viene vacío en el índice $codigo el producto ya se elimino de la Session

Comment: @Yussef no hay problema en esa parte